# Save control state when form is closed

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, state

Hi I am trying to save the color state of this 4x4 grid of buttons created dynamically using a 2D array into an xml document:

[image]

However when I press save I keep getting this message:

I can make this work if I use a one dimensional array for the buttons but that will not give me the grid that I want but when I use a 2D array for the buttons it wont work:

[image]

What can I change so I can get this to work any suggestion are much appreciated:

This is my code that I have:

`FormState` class:

```
public class FormState
{
    public string ButtonBackColor { get; set; }
}
```

Form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        int col = 4;
        int row = 4;
        Button[,] buttons;
        FormState[,] states;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buttons = new Button[col, row];
            states = new FormState[col, row];
        }

        public void placeRows()
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
            {
                createColumns(r);
            }
        }

        public void createColumns(int r)
        {
            int s = r * 25; //gap
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
            {
                buttons[r, c] = new Button();
                buttons[r, c].SetBounds(75 * c, s, 75, 25);
                buttons[r, c].Text = Convert.ToString(c);
                buttons[r, c].Click += new EventHandler(grid_Click);
                panel1.Controls.Add(buttons[r, c]);
            }
        }

        int count = 0;
        //backcolor change
        void grid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;

            if (count == 0)
            {
                button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                count++;
            }

            else if (count == 1)
            {
                button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                count--;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            placeRows();

            if (File.Exists("config.xml"))
            {
                loadConfig();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
                {
                    if (states[i,j] != null)
                    {
                        buttons[i,j].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(states[i,j].ButtonBackColor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //method to load file
        private void loadConfig()
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormState[]));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("config.xml"))
            {
                states = (FormState[,])ser.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }

        private void writeConfig()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
                {
                    if (states[i,j] == null)
                    {
                        states[i,j] = new FormState();
                    }
                    states[i,j].ButtonBackColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(buttons[i,j].BackColor);
                }

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("config.xml"))
                {
                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormState[]));
                    ser.Serialize(sw, states);
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writeConfig();
        }
    }
```

Comment: click on "View Detail" in your exception, it probablly says your class is not marked serializable

Comment: No it says: {"There was an error generating the XML document."}

Comment: and if you keep drilling in? Inner exception?

Comment: nop doesn't show me anything like that

Comment: the problem is you can't serialize multi dimensional arrays, so you will have to convert to another form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an ideal solution (and I haven't tried it, so it may not even work), but you could create a nested array instead of a 2-D array.  Something like

```
FormStates[][] states = new FormStates[row][];
for(Int32 i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    states[i] = new FormStates[col];
}
```

Instead of indexing using `states[i, j]`, you would use `states[i][j]`.  Since 1-D arrays are serializable, this might work.

**Edit**

Slightly longer example, based on your code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int col = 4;
    int row = 4;
    Button[][] buttons;
    FormState[][] states;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttons = new Button[col][];
        states = new FormState[col][];
        for(Int32 c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            buttons[c] = new Button[row];
            states[c] = new FormState[row];
        }
    }

    public void createColumns(int r)
    {
        int s = r * 25; //gap
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            buttons[r][c] = new Button();
            buttons[r][c].SetBounds(75 * c, s, 75, 25);
            buttons[r][c].Text = Convert.ToString(c);
            buttons[r][c].Click += new EventHandler(grid_Click);
            panel1.Controls.Add(buttons[r][c]);
        }
    }
}
```

This should be enough to give you the syntax to change the rest of your code.

You will also want to change your `XmlSerializer` declarations to use `typeof(FormState[][])` instead of just `typeof(FormState[])`.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a longer example please

Comment: I edited my answer to include a longer example (based on the code you posted).  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I haven't put much thought into this but as per comments you cant serialize multi dimensional arrays so you might:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class FormState
    {
        public int RowIndex { get; set; }
        public int ColIndex { get; set; }
        public string BackColor { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Layout : Collection<FormState> { 

        public Layout(){}
    }
```

..

```
        public void SomeCallingMethod() {
            Layout l = new Layout();
            foreach (FormState fs in l) {
                buttons[fs.RowIndex, fs.ColIndex].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(fs.BackColor);
            }     
        }
```

Or use a List if necessary and serialize that.

Comment: where is SomeCallingMethod() located and called?